# Ubuntu can not shutdown on battery

Tags: ubuntu, battery, shutdown

My laptop is Thinkpad x220, installed with Ubuntu 12.04, gnome 3 desktop.
It can normally shutdown before. But yesterday, it can not shutdown when on battery(neither use `power off` button nor `shutdown` command), but on AC power, it still shutdown normally. So can anybody give me some suggestion?

I didn't install any software update before the problem occured.

UPDATE1: there's no error, it just stuck in the shutdown screen, the cpu was still working, but there was no disk io at all.

UPDATE2: I've post the [the dmesg output](http://pastebin.com/SHZBYJrR) to pastebin

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail there's no error, it just stuck in the shutdown screen, the cpu was still working, but there was no disk io at all.

Comment: What's the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: try: "shutdown -h now" in a command line interface like gnome-terminal

Comment: @l1zard I mentioned this in my post. I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail the dmesg output is too long, how can i post it?

Comment: use pastebin.com

Comment: Oops, I meant to ask for the previous session's dmesg (`/var/log/dmesg.0`). This is because running `dmesg` gives the current session's, but we want to see what happened at the end of the previous session (when it hung on shutdown, and presumably you force-powered off). Could you post that?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail ok, the link is updated

Answer (score 0):

The discussion on this page will help you:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968376

It talks about the shut down problems.

Comment: I've see this before, but this doesn't match my situation, I don't have nvidia driver. And my computer just have problem from yesterday, it have already works fine for months

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the package "laptop-mode-tool", and it will work! 
I have the same problem on my openSUSE, and this works for me.